# Want to move a particular div to right

Tags: css

I want to move a particular div more to the right side so that the div in the left gets some more space to display the contents in it.

I tried few things in CSS, but I know I am doing something wrong.

In CSS, I have...

```
login-box {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: "Tried few things in css but i know i am doing something wrong." Feel free to share those things with us so we know what you're talking about. :)

Comment: Could you give us your current script so to give you a better answer? It's a very vague question.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use float on that particular div, e.g.

```
<div style="float:right;">
```

Float the div you want more space to have to the left as well:

```
<div style="float:left;">
```

If all else fails give the div on the right position:absolute and then move it as right as you want it to be.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:-500px; top:30px;">
```

etc. Obviously put the style in a seperate stylesheet but this is just a quicker example.

Comment: I am using it. that div is already to the right. I want to push it more to right

Comment: dont kno wy but <div style="position:absolute; left:-500px; top:30px;">   dint work either

Comment: I use `float: right;margin-right: 100px;` to have the div on the right end with 100px margin.

Answer (score 36):

I used `margin-left: auto;` which is more responsive with horizontal resizing.

Comment: This works perfectly for responsive too, thanks. If you use position:absolute sometimes it doesn't work responsively.

Comment: for margin-left: auto work a width must be given so that it pushes itself to the right end
it can be also achieved with flex and is also responsive `display: flex; justify-content: end;` and `float: right` give you desired result also

Answer (score 23):

This will do the job:

```html
<div style="position:absolute; right:0;">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
login-box {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: To make your answer a good answer, please explain why your answer works

Comment: sure sir, I will try to improve myself and my answer thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

(this adds as much left margin as there is room for)

```
div{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
}
```